# Couldn't connect to TWS

Tags: python, ib-api

I can't connect to TWS. I've confirmed that "Enable ActiveX and Socket EClients" is enabled and connection port is the same as "Socket Port" on the TWS.

```
import ibapi
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper

class IBApi(EWrapper,EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        
class Bot:
    ib=None
    def __init__(self):
        ib=IBApi()
        ib.connect("127.0.0.1",7497,1)
        ib.run()
bot=Bot()
```

I tried changing the port number, but I was not able to also change it from Interactive Broker Client App.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below to see if it is indeed connected

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.next_order_id = None

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        print(f"Received next valid order ID: {orderId}")
        self.next_order_id = orderId

app = EClient(MyWrapper())

# Connect to TWS/Gateway API
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=0)

if app.isConnected():
    print("Connected to TWS/Gateway API!")
else:
    print("Not connected to TWS/Gateway API")

# Disconnect from TWS/Gateway API
app.disconnect()
```

Else you may try to create new environment with the modules installed then try to run ibapi in that new environment, it worked for me